# Library versions in Windows Azure Cloud Services

Tags: iis, dll, azure

So, we deployed an application to Windows Azure and it crashed there for no apparent reason. After debugging it for a while we encountered an error that appeared due to Razor engine parsing failure. This was somewhat surprising as the application worked just fine on a local IIS Express. The error seemed to be caused by a different version of the Razor view engine in Azure Cloud Service and local IIS Express.

Apparently not everything is deployed to Azure when the application is and seems like the Razor view engine is one of those libraries which is NOT deployed with the actual project or red from any configuration file. This was somewhat surprising to me as I was pretty sure that  everything is either deployed with the application package OR checked from a configuration file and a correct version is used in the Azure IIS. It seems a bit silly to use different versions that might cause bugs in the applications running in the Azure environment.

Now the question is;  **What is actually deployed or "installed" to the Azure Cloud Service IIS based on the configuration files in the application to be deployed and what is not?**

I didn't find any information about this and am curious about how the actual Azure cloud service configuration is done upon the application deployment.

Also another question; **What version of IIS is Azure Cloud Service actually using?**

Answer (score 0):

Your Azure PAAS machines are very basic and contain default installs of Windows server.  You want to make sure that anything outside of the .NET framework is deployed with your application (e.g. CopyLocal is true), ie; MVC, RDLC, etc.

It is one of the more common deployment vows, as your solution may rely on the .DLL's from the GAC while your deployed to Azure server will not have the same stuff in GAC.  So, paying attention to CopyLocal is very important.